# Swift 4 program showing data after downloading images but data is not related

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, alamofire

I am making a swift app where i am downloading data from API. which gives a JSON.And from there i am putting image url in an imageArray and movieTiteUrl in movieTitleArray. but when i am showing them to collection view they are showing data but that data is not related. To download images i am using AlamofireImage Below code will help you to understand my problem better.

> inside ViewDidLoad

```
var imageUrlArray = [String]()
var imageArray = [UIImage]()
var movieTitleArray = [String]()
```

> UICollectionViewDelegate

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "movieCell", for: indexPath) as? MovieCell else { return UICollectionViewCell() }
    cell.movieName.image = imageArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.movieNameLbl.text = movieTitleArray[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

> An extension which download data and download images

```
func downloadImages(handler: @escaping (_ status: Bool)-> ()){
    imageArray = []
    movieTitleArray = []
    for url in imageUrlArray{
        Alamofire.request(url).responseImage(completionHandler: { (response) in
            guard let image = response.result.value else { return }
            self.imageArray.append(image)

            if self.imageArray.count == self.imageUrlArray.count {
                handler(true)
            }

        })
    }
}

func retriveData(handler : @escaping (_ status: Bool) -> ()){
    print(getPopularMovies(pageNumber: 1))
    Alamofire.request(getPopularMovies(pageNumber: 1)).responseJSON { (response) in

        guard let json = response.result.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> else { return }
        let dataDictArray = json["results"] as! [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]

        for data in dataDictArray {

            guard let imageUrl = data["poster_path"] as? String else { return }
            guard let name = data["original_title"] as? String else { return }
            let updatedImageUrl = getFullImageUrl(imageUrl: imageUrl)
            self.imageUrlArray.append(updatedImageUrl)
            self.movieTitleArray.append(name)

        }
        handler(true)
    }
}

func updateDataToCollectionView(){
    retriveData{(finished) in
        if finished{
            self.downloadImages(handler: { (finishedDownloadingImage) in
                if finishedDownloadingImage{
                    self.movieCollectionView.reloadData()
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found two observation ( problems ).

1. As you are using **Async request to download the images**, it is not guaranteed that you will get the response in the requested order. for example, if you request **movie1Image**,**movie2Image**....it is not guarntee that first you will receive **movie1Image** and the **movie2Image** in the same order. So definitely it is not reliable. **use Dictionary to solve this. [String:Data]** string -> ImageUrl, Data -> ImageData
2. Why did you wait till all images get downloaded? any specific scenario or any business requirement. Ideally, for a greater User Experience and for interaction, **it is not recommended to wait till all the images get downloaded.**